Civievent 5.73.2 register participant is different from online registration
I have an online registration with a profile that has the participant role field and custom participant fields that depend on the chosen participant role. When I use the register participant link to enter a new participant, then the fields I can enter change depending on the role entered, as it should.
When I use the online registration form the fields for all roles are shown and I when I select the participant role field, there is no change in the fields show.
It looks like the online registration doesn’t use JavaScript but is just an html form?
I would like to provide the functionality provided in the “register participant” form for online participants, is there a way I can achieve that?

If you are wanting Profiles to provide 'conditional fields' then you are likely to need an Extension such as https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals

Thanks, it took some time to understand and trial and error but that is working now.
Really appreciated!
